# Can one explain me why there is a background border in my menu items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wished I could post a fiddle here, but it's a whole joomla CMS site, it just won't work. Anyway, just open the console and you'll see what I'm talking about. As the image below shows, there are black borders around my menu items (Look where the cursor is pointing), but I didn't configure them, actually I've settle `border:none;` in css, it's like some kind of glitchy background just appeared.

[image]

You can check it in the top white menu at http://lucrebem.com.br using your browser console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because the button container has a black background color. Offending css:

```
.top_menu ul.subul_main {
    background: #3D464B;
}
```

When you add border radius to an element, the part of the element that is cut away is transparent.

Set the background color of the menu button container to the same orange as the background of the menu.

Comment: Heyyyy thx, I searched eveywhere in the code and couldn't think about that. Wwhat about using `transparent`?

Comment: Thx mate, my problem is finally solved. Owe you a beer.

Comment: @user3692451 No worries, have fun coding!

Answer (score 0):

`.subul_main li.level1 { background: #ff8400; }`

Comment: Welcome. Code only answers are discouraged in SO. Please consider adding some explanation to this answer.